# How can I validate radio buttons before going to next page?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I have a form where I have radio buttons, before i go to the next page I want to validate them before 
I click on 'NEXT' button.

```
 <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="4">
                 <cfset question = GetEmployeeCSEDepts["csedept_question" & i][GetEmployeeCSEDepts.CurrentRow]>
                   <cfif question neq "">
                       <tr>
                        <cfif i is 1><td>Leadership <br/>               
                        </td></cfif>
                        <cfif i is 2><td>Integrity<br/>                     
                        </td></cfif>
                        <cfif i is 3><td>Service<br/>
                        </td></cfif>
                        <cfif i is 4><td>Teamwork<br/>          
                        </td></cfif>

                         <td valign="top">    <div align="center">  <input type="radio" name="sltRating#i#" value="5"></div><br></td>
                            <td valign="top"><div align="center">       <input type="radio" name="sltRating#i#" value="4.5"></div><br></td>
                            <td valign="top"><div align="center">       <input type="radio" name="sltRating#i#" value="4"></div><br></td>
                            <td valign="top">   <div align="center">    <input type="radio" name="sltRating#i#" value="3.5"></div><br></td>

                     </tr>
                  </cfif>
                </cfloop>
```

When I click on the 'next' I get error 'ReferenceError: validateNext is not defined'.
Maybe this is not the best way to do this.
How can I make it work?

```
 <button type="button" id="btnNext" onclick="validateNext()">Next </button>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function validateNext(){
if (!document.feedback.field[0].checked &&
!document.feedback.field[1].checked &&
!document.feedback.field[2].checked) && !document.feedback.field[2].checked){
    // no radio button is selected
    alert ('please make sure all questions are check');
    return false;
}
console.log('testing');
}

</script>
```

Comment: Did you try placing the script before your button definition?

Comment: <cfinput required="yes"> is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: @talor yes i have try both ways , before and after.

Comment: From a usability perspective, you might want to change your radio buttons to checkboxes.  Radio buttons are normally associated with choices, as in choose one of these buttons.  You want the user to choose them all.

Comment: `cfinput` is NEVER the right answer. Ever.

Comment: @scottstroz: agree. Dan: don't recommend CFINPUT, pls

Comment: I acknowlege the opinion that cfform, etc is bad.  But I don't share it.  That being the case, I think it's better to use a product's features rather than re-inventing them.

Comment: Even if those features are reinventing other features and are poorly implemented? Using your argument, you should NOT be using `cfinput` as it is just ColdFusion re-inventing `input`. I would prefer to use features written by people who are experts in that field. CF engineers are NOT web developers, therefore, their HTML & JS skills are not up to the same level as those who write, let's say, jQuery.

Comment: You are - of course - entitled to your opinion, Dan. But it's not a well-formed one, so I really wish you'd not be so ready to share it. Do you not think that given the bulk of the CFML community *including the Adobe CF Team* disagree with you... there might be something to it?

Comment: I think that witholding an opinion is a disservice to people looking for information.  I would rather have them presented with all available information and decide for themselves what approach to take.

Comment: Sorry mate: bad advice is worse than no advice.

Comment: I am all for giving options, but would prefer viable options. `cfinput` and the rest of the CF UI features are not viable options. They are poorly implemented and are limited in scope, performance and features. EVERY time I have tried to implement a solution using one of them, I wound up eventually starting over and doing it the right way because of some limitation or wonky implementation. And yes, Dan, if you use `cfinput` or any other CF UI feature, you are doing it the wrong way. If you recommend others use them, doubly so.

Comment: @DanBracuk I have tried to write a comment a few different ways to express to you how much telling people to use cfinput is just wrong.  Wrong on more levels I can think of.  Yes, that is opinion, but an opinion backed with over a decade of experience.  However, I fear that it will just fall on deaf ears.

Comment: wow guys very interesting discussion, I even did some research on which is better right after i read this, i did get my code to work now, and i do use 'input' but i can see where the cfinput people are coming from from researching

Comment: "I think that witholding an opinion is a disservice to people looking for information." -- Even an opinion that most experienced CFML developers think is completely the wrong approach? I don't see how presenting people with a terrible idea as the recommended solution is doing anyone any kind of service. The built-in CFML UI tags are poorly implemented and extremely limited. They were useful in their day but they are just plain wrong today - and it's clear the OP is already far beyond needing them.

Comment: @user3591637 - they are coming from a world of not knowing how to write code the right way, that is where they are coming from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an extra bracket in your if statement. Remove that and try it again.

```
if (!document.feedback.field[0].checked &&
!document.feedback.field[1].checked &&
!document.feedback.field[2].checked && !document.feedback.field[2].checked)
```

Edited : It could be an issue with your html formatting may be your 'form' tag is not well formed. In addition, instead of using field[0] use explicitly name of input field.

```
 <cfoutput>
    <form name="feedback">
      <table>
    <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="4">
                         <cfset question = GetEmployeeCSEDepts["csedept_question" & i][GetEmployeeCSEDepts.CurrentRow]>

        <cfif question neq "">
            <tr>
            <cfif i is 1><td>Leadership <br/>
            </td></cfif>
            <cfif i is 2><td>Integrity<br/>
            </td></cfif>
            <cfif i is 3><td>Service<br/>
            </td></cfif>
            <cfif i is 4><td>Teamwork<br/>
            </td></cfif>

                <td valign="top">   <div align="center">   <input type="radio"  name="sltRating#i#" value="5"></div><br></td>
                <td valign="top">   <div align="center">   <input type="radio"  name="sltRating#i#" value="4.5"></div><br></td>
                <td valign="top">   <div align="center">   <input type="radio"  name="sltRating#i#" value="4"></div><br></td>
                <td valign="top">   <div align="center">   <input type="radio"  name="sltRating#i#" value="3.5"></div><br></td>

            </tr>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    </table>
        <button type="button" id="btnNext" onclick="return validateNext();">Next </button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function validateNext(){

            if($("input:radio[name='sltRating1']").is(":checked") && $("input:radio[name='sltRating2']").is(":checked") && $("input:radio[name='sltRating3']").is(":checked") &&$("input:radio[name='sltRating4']").is(":checked") ){

                alert ('please make sure all questions are check');
                return false;
            }

        }

    </script>
    </cfoutput>
```

Comment: thanks, this work,now i see the message, but the problem it seems , that even if it gives me message, it still takes me to other page

Comment: Add return when you called the function.  onclick="return validateNext();"

Comment: yeah i try that at first , but adding it still goes to the next page, no errors

Comment: @user3591637 What's the 'type of your button'? is it 'Submit'?

Comment: its not a submit, it just a next button, stays on the same form but hides the above code and show the new questions , staying on the same form ,  <button type="button" id="btnNext" onclick="return validateNext();">Next </button>

Comment: I tested this code, works fine for me. Not sure, why it's not working for you. May be there are some other JS functions causing issue. I would say double check all js functions which are using button id 'btnNext'.

Comment: i do have another fuction that does the show and hide....$('#btnNext').click(function() {
    $('#panel1').hide('fast', function() {
        $('#panel2').show('fast');
    });
});

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58393/discussion-between-user3591637-and-ronnie7777).

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because the script tag is after the call to validateNext.

JavaScript is executed in order so you need to declare the script before using in an onclick. Or better yet use unobtrusive javascript

Quick Fix:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function validateNext(){
if (!document.feedback.field[0].checked &&
!document.feedback.field[1].checked &&
!document.feedback.field[2].checked) && !document.feedback.field[2].checked){
    // no radio button is selected
    alert ('please make sure all questions are check');
    return false;
}
console.log('testing');
}
</script>
<button type="button" id="btnNext" onclick="validateNext()">Next </button>
```

Better Fix:

```
<button type="button" id="btnNext">Next </button>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 var button = document.getElementById("btnNext");
 button.addEventListener('click', validateNext, false);

function validateNext(){
    if (!document.feedback.field[0].checked &&
    !document.feedback.field[1].checked &&
    !document.feedback.field[2].checked) && !document.feedback.field[2].checked){
        // no radio button is selected
        alert ('please make sure all questions are check');
        return false;
    }
    console.log('testing');
}
```

Notice I removed onclick from the html entirely.

Comment: i have try this and i think it may have to do with something else 
since i get this error, TypeError: document.feedback.field is undefined
with both ways

Comment: Lol, @Hattan Shobokshi  Did you even run this?

Comment: What's funny? No I didn't set up a test page for it. But I guess I incorretly assumed that what was in validateNext works. However, the issue I looked at still stands as OP will still get an error with the snipped in the original post.

@user3591637less  - Where is feedback defined in the markup?